# OpenCL Copy-Once Share a lot

Tags: opencl

I am implementing a solution using OpenCL and I want to do the following thing, say for example you have a large array of data that you want to copy in the GPU once and have many kernels process batches of it and store the results in their specific output buffers.

The actual question is here which way is faster? En-queue each kernel with the portion of the array it needs to have or pass out the whole array before hand an let each kernel (in the same context) process the required batch, since they would have the same address space and could each map the array concurrently. Of course the said array is read-only but is not constant as it changes every time I execute the kernel(s)... (so I could cache it using a global memory buffer).

Also if the second way is actually faster could you point me with direction on how this could be implemented, as I haven't found anything concrete yet (although I am still searching :)).

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the second memory normally.  Sharing the memory is easy.  Just pass the same buffer to each kernel.  I do this in my real-time ray-tracer.  I render with one kernel and post-process (image process) with another.

Using the C++ bindings it looks something like this

```
cl_input_mem = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_uchar4)*npixels, NULL, &err);

kernel_render.setArg(0, cl_input_mem);
kernel_postprocess.setArg(0, cl_input_mem);
```

If you want one kernel to operate on a different segment of the array/memory you can pass an offset value to the kernel arguments and add that to e.g. the global memory pointer for each kernel.

I would use the first method if the array (actually the sum of each buffer - including output) does not fit in memory.  Another reason to use the first method is if you're running on multiple devices.  In my ray tracer I use the first method when I render on multiple devices.  For example I have one GTX 580 render the upper half of the screen and the other GTX 580 rendering the lower half (actually I do this dynamically so one device may render 30% while the other 70% but that's besides the point).  I have each device only render it's fraction of the output and then I assemble the output on the CPU.  With PCI 3.0 the transfer back and forth between CPU and GPU (multiple times) has a negligible effect on the frame rate even for 1920x1080 images.

Comment: Just a comment: One problem with the transfer is that the buffer is locked. You can get slightly better performance using double buffering.

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you mean have two render buffers and when you read from one you don't wait but start the next kernel and write to the other?

Comment: Yes something like that, I was just thinking in your raytracer. I would try something like that, unless you create a new output buffer each frame. But just a thought and I don't know your architecture :)

Comment: That's probably a good idea.  But round trip transfers across the PCI bus currently are insignificant.  They consume something on the order of less than 10 ms in total which is only 1/100 FPS lost.